# Jagged shadows in Bender 2.9

Tags: error

Shadows in Bender 2.9 appear jagged or serrated. Is there any way to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: Shadows in Bender 2.9 appear jagged or jagged. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Try using denoising, or higher sample count.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information.

Comment: could you please share your file? If you are in Eevee and your sampling value is very low you'll have bad shadows

Comment: Thanks for the repply, I used denoise node and this improved my model, at last, I found out that Eevee doesn't render shadows as well as Cyles.